# Non-existence of a diffeomorphism between $A=\{(x,y):x>0,y>0\}$ and $B=\{(x,y):x>0 ∨ y<0\}$ that is smooth beyond the boundaries

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $A=\{ (x,y): x>0, y>0\}$ and $B=\{ (x,y): x>0 \ \vee\  y<0\}$

Show that no there diffeomorphism  $f:U \rightarrow V$ such that $\overline{A}\subset U$ and $\overline{B}\subset V$ with $f(\overline{A})=B$.

I would like to understand this exercise to start trying to find an example of diffeomorphism $C^{\infty}$ between $A$ and $B$, any suggestions??

Comment: Notice that $B=f(\overline{A})=(f^{-1})^{-1}(\overline{A})$ whereas $f^{-1}$ is continuous, $\overline{A}$ is closed and $B$ is not closed...

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion for a diffeomorphism between $A$ and $B$: use polar coordinates, with polar angle $\theta$ taken from $(-\pi,\pi]$.  Indeed, $A=\{0<\theta<\pi/2\}$ and $B=\{-\pi<\theta<\pi/2\}$. So, the map $(r,\theta)\to (r,3\theta-\pi)$ is a diffeomorphism from $A$ onto $B$.

However, this map is not smooth at the origin, which is the essence of the problem with $U$ and $V$. The comment by Seirios addresses the impossibility of $f(\overline{A})=B$. But there's a chance you actually meant $f(A)=B$. It's still impossible to have such $f$ which is also   a diffeomorphism of $U$ onto $V$. Consider the derivative of $f^{-1}$ at $(0,0)$: it will map $B$ onto some angle of opening $3\pi/2$, which cannot be contained in $A$. Use the definition of derivative to show $f^{-1}(B)$ cannot be contained in $A$.